# table formatting when rendering as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have a visual force page they want rendered as a PDF. Formatting looks great until I add renderAs="PDF" to the apex:page options. The background color and formatting works when rendered as a PDF until I use apex:repeat to fill the data into the table. All formatting gets removed. How do I solve this problem

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="mevCustServPortal" action="{!genSSReport}" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false">
  <head>
    <style> 
      @page { 
        size:landscape;
        @bottom-left { content: element(footer); }
        @bottom-right { content: element(mevDate); } 
      }
      div.footer { display: block; position: running(footer); }
      div.mevDate { display: block; position: running(mevDate); text-align:right; }  
    </style>
    <title>S250 Case Status</title>
  </head>
  
<body>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white; backfont-size: 1.25em; padding: 4px 0px" colspan="6">{!rptHeader}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 7%; text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white;">Status</td>
        <td style="width: 6%; text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white;">Date</td>
        <td style="width: 8%; text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white;">Case Number</td>
        <td style="width: 26%; text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white;">Subject</td>
        <td style="width: 27%; text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white;">Description</td>
        <td style="width: 26%; text-align: center; background-color: #d31245; color: white;">Status and Next Steps</td>
      </tr>
      <apex:repeat value="{!ACSReport}" var="rl">
        <tr>
          <td style="{!IF(rl.s1=='Open','text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; padding: 2px 2px',IF(rl.s1='Monitoring','text-align: center; background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px 2px','background-color: lightgray; padding: 2px 2px; text-align: center'))}">{!rl.s1}</td>                  
          <td style="{!IF(rl.s1=='Open','text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; padding: 2px 2px',IF(rl.s1='Monitoring','text-align: center; background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px 2px','background-color: lightgray; padding: 2px 2px; text-align: center'))}">{!rl.s2}</td>
          <td style="{!IF(rl.s1=='Open','text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; padding: 2px 2px',IF(rl.s1='Monitoring','text-align: center; background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px 2px','background-color: lightgray; padding: 2px 2px; text-align: center'))}">{!rl.s3}</td>
          <td style="{!IF(rl.s1=='Open','background-color: lightgreen; padding: 2px 2px',IF(rl.s1='Monitoring','background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px 2px','background-color: lightgray; padding: 2px 2px'))}">{!rl.s4}</td>
          <td style="{!IF(rl.s1=='Open','background-color: lightgreen; padding: 2px 2px',IF(rl.s1='Monitoring','background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px 2px','background-color: lightgray; padding: 2px 2px'))}">{!rl.s5}</td>
          <td style="{!IF(rl.s1=='Open','background-color: lightgreen; padding: 2px 2px',IF(rl.s1='Monitoring','background-color: lightblue; padding: 2px 2px','background-color: lightgray; padding: 2px 2px'))}">{!rl.s6}</td>
        </tr>
      </apex:repeat>

    </table>
    
  </body>
  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. I'd start by just hard-coding the `style` to one of the styles (to eliminate the `IF` logic) and assuming the colours work for that, build back up from there.

Comment: already did that. The parts before apex:repeat work fine. After apex:repeat it seems to ignore whatever I put in the style or create a css class and use class.

Comment: I have a repeat containing `<td class="user-input-value"... ` where the class name is defined inside `<html><head><style>...` and that generates the expected output as a PDF. You could try that instead; bit less duplication of styling too. [Flying Saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) has its quirks and AFAIK is still be being used by SF.